# VBScript if condition specific

Tags: if-statement, vbscript, conditional-statements

I'd like create specific condition "IF", but I don't know how.

I need create one scprit do something when user digit specifics numbers. For example:

If String = "" or String = 0 and > 5 Then.....

Script only do something if user digit: 1,2,3,4

Anybody know how to create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways.

1. Convert the string to a number and test the bounds:

   ```
   If IsNumeric(someString) Then

       i = CLng(someString)

       If i >= 1 And i <= 4 Then
           ' Match
       End If

   End If
   ```
2. Use `Select Case` and you can specify multiple values to match:

   ```
   Select Case someString
       Case "1", "2", "3", "4"
           ' Match
   End Select
   ```

Or, if you just want to do multiple individual tests, here's the basic `If` structure:

```
If someString = "1" Or someString = "2" Or someString = "3" Or someString = "4" Then
End If
```